# HttpRequestFailed with taq originate counter.tz from quickstart

Tags: smart-contracts

I apologise in advance if the question I am trying to ask is trivial and not very interesting.

I have just started to get interested in the tezos blockchain and its tools and I am encountering an error that I cannot solve.

To start with my computer is a macbook pro M1 2020.

The problem comes from the quickstart documentation:
https://taqueria.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart/

when I get to the step where I have to use the following command

```
taq originate counter.tz
```

I get a response:
Error while performing operation:

```
HttpRequestFailed: GET http://localhost:20000/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6/manager_key Error: socket hang up {
  "name": "HttpRequestFailed"
}
No operations performed
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise

Theo

Comment: Are you running a Flextesa sandbox? The URL http://localhost:20000 is typically a Flextesa sandbox blockchain

Comment: That's correct, and you can see from the error message that it's not a 404 error. I believe it's something else, but I'm not sure what. When I tested it with Postman, I received a 200 response, indicating that everything is working correctly.

Comment: when I make this request :
"http://localhost:20000/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6/manager_key" 
I get this answer
"edpkurPsQ8eUApnLUJ9ZPDvu98E8VNj4KtJa1aZr16Cr5ow5VHKnz4"
I think the problem is with taq cli or maybe directly with my computer, I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the exact same error going through taqueria [Quickstart](https://taqueria.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart/) guide.

Just like you, I used node 19 version, but on Linux. I saw the [issue](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taqueria/issues/1848) that you created and noticed that reinstalling the node helped you. I installed nvm in order to be able to switch to the v16 node and I then I succeed to run the `taq originate counter.tz` command.

I'm leaving this answer for anyone else who runs into this problem:

1. In order to install nvm, you can follow the instructions on [nvm repository](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
2. Then you will need to install the 16th node using the `nvm install 16` command
3. After that, you probably need to restart your bash and then you will be able to the `taq originate counter.tz` command. In my case it ran without any problems and resulted in the same way as it was expected in tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to originate the contract?

- locally, you will need to run a flextesa sandbox.
- ghostnet/testnet, you can use the --env parameter for the taq originate.
- mainnet, same as for ghostnet, you can provide an environment using the --env parameter.

For more details on how to use/set up an environment, you can check the taqueria config.json [here](https://taqueria.io/docs/config/config-files/#example-configjson).

Comment: I do it with a local node. I do use flextesa sandbox. 
I follow the tutorial exactly to be honest but I can't do ```taq originate counter.tz``` by the way all the previous steps work

Comment: the following command ```taq list accounts local``` gives me what is expected

Comment: Are you sure that flextesa sandbox is running on port 20000? If you are running on linux, you can check that using `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 20000`

Comment: I'm on macos. And yes I'm sure that the flextesa sandbox is running on the port 20000 because i've send a request with postman and I double check with docker.

Comment: when I make this request :
"http://localhost:20000/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6/manager_key" 
I get this answer
"edpkurPsQ8eUApnLUJ9ZPDvu98E8VNj4KtJa1aZr16Cr5ow5VHKnz4"
I think the problem is with taq cli or maybe directly with my computer, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your sandbox has been started by running `docker ps` - you should see output that includes `oxheadalpha/flextesa` in the output:

```
b20f0d4bc388   oxheadalpha/flextesa:20221123                 "/bin/sh"                6 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:20002->20000/tcp   taq-flextesa-local-4535c
```

If you don't find that in the output, then you'll need to start your sandbox by running `taq start sandbox`.

If you do have a sandbox up and running, sometimes you need to give the sandbox 10-30 seconds to fully boot before you can inject an operation. This is a known issue that we're working on:
https://github.com/ecadlabs/taqueria/issues/1846

If you think that issue is what you're running into, then just retry running `taq originate counter.tz` again after giving the sandbox some time to start.

Please post back if you continue to have issues and I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: I give 2h to the docker image but nothing change i've got the same error...

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue could be related to my Node.js version. I'm currently using version 19.4.0, whereas I noticed on GitHub that you're using an earlier version.

Comment: when I make this request :
"http://localhost:20000/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1aSkwEot3L2kmUvcoxzjMomb9mvBNuzFK6/manager_key" 
I get this answer
"edpkurPsQ8eUApnLUJ9ZPDvu98E8VNj4KtJa1aZr16Cr5ow5VHKnz4"
I think the problem is with taq cli or maybe directly with my computer, I don't really know.